# node.js and push notifications

Tags: node.js, push-notification

I'm quite new on `Node.js` and without any knowledge on mobile development apps but I would add push notifications into my server app.
On npm I found this module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications

but, after some search and if I understand well, I should have some specific credentials for sending notifications to all devices, first question is: is correct?

Assuming that the answer is yes, are there something to jump this check? Another module, some test credentials or what you want?
I would some generic solution but, if it is not possible, it could be useful also an IOS compatible solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is the best packages for push notification for nodejs:

- ios: https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn
- android: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Matej Maloča but tell me a thing, I must create an app for ios/android if I want send a notification right?

Comment: Yes, u need it. If you are javascript guy just make some hibrid app like nativescript, ionic or react native...

Answer (score 1):

APNS is a push notification service for apple(mobile) devices.

You need to integrate SDK's provided by the 'apple developer doc' in your app to integrate push notification services. Then, Once the app installs in the mobile a token will be generated(unique for a specific device).You need to save this token.

From your server side You can send the push notifications to a device with the token that you got.

There is also an SDK to send Push notification from server side.

The best Provider is AWS, you can check this in details by [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, if I understand well, the push notifications can't be send from a web app right?

Comment: since mobile app uses webservices(restfull now a days), it should be sent from a webservices, but also from webapp, but it is not recomended