# Push notification system in Nodejs with Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, node.js, push-notification

I want to create a push notification system in `nodejs`, which will be suitable for both **iOS** and **Android**. I've been searching, and at the moment I am thinking about this one:

http://devcenter.kinvey.com/nodejs/guides/push

Can anyone, who has been working on something like this, tell me what is the best way to implement that?

Comment: I think I found the best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930285/node-js-and-push-notifications

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to use Firebase Cloud Message (FCM), you can send notifications to your Android and iOS devices over an fcm_token provided by Firebase SDK. It's Google solution and simple to use.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?refresh=1

If you dont like Google, this is an other 100% free option that allow you to do the same job, One Signal.

https://onesignal.com/

Answer (score 0):

Another commercial option is Twilio: https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/send-notifications